# How to override class DefaultScreenNameValidator in liferay 7?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I am trying to override a class `DefaultScreenNameValidator` that implements `ScreenNameValidator` interface. For this , I copied the class and put it into another module. One change that I made is in annotation that is as follows:-

```
@Component(
        property = {
                "service.ranking:Integer=500"
                }

    )
```

I got a successful build using this. But when I tried to deploy the project, I got error as `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/portal/kernel/security/auth/ScreenNameValidator`.Can you suggest me how to eradicate this error. Thanx in advance..

Comment: Could you share your `build.gradle` and `bnd.bnd` files to us?

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering, wouldn't it be better to instead create a module that also implements the `ScreenNameValidator` interface, and define your custom logic in there? Then you can just simply tell Liferay to use that validator instead of the `DefaultScreenNameValidator`.

For example, a minimalistic implementation:

```
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.security.auth.ScreenNameValidator;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

@Component(
    immediate = true,
    service = ScreenNameValidator.class
)
public class CustomScreenNameValidator implements ScreenNameValidator {

    @Override
    public boolean validate(long companyId, String screenName) {
        // Your custom logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the dependency to portal-kernel in the build.gradle

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.liferay.portal:com.liferay.portal.kernel:2.0.0'
```

I made a screenNameValidator using blade-cli  you can see the projet at https://github.com/bruinen/liferay-blade-samples/tree/master/liferay-workspace/modules/blade.screenname.validator

```
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.security.auth.ScreenNameValidator;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

import java.util.Locale;

@Component(
        immediate = true,
        property = {"service.ranking:Integer=100"},
        service = ScreenNameValidator.class
)
public class CustomScreenNameValidator implements ScreenNameValidator {

    @Override
    public String getAUIValidatorJS() {
        return "function(val) {return !(val.indexOf(\"admin\") !==-1)}";
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription(Locale locale) {
        return "The screenName contains reserved words";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validate(long companyId, String screenName) {
        return !screenName.contains("admin");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro for ur reply..I made a project same as given in the link but no effect..I mean it deployed successfully but method validate() is not called..Plz help..thanx in advance..

Comment: Can you check if is set  service.rank try giving a major number